# Creating a secure strcpy for C that handles the inability to check for source/destination length

Tags: c, memory, error-handling, buffer

As far as I understand the C goal for string/buffer lengths is to trust that the user of the function is giving correct source/destination lengths as parameters? I am attempting to write a strcpy similar to strlcpy, but one that avoids undefined behavior from writing into memory that is not allocated for that destination buffer.

My work below is what I have so far and I can only see a way to do this that trusts that the destination size is not asking for an operation in more space than the destination buffer actually has.

***Is there anyway to improve this/a better option?***

```c
static bool s_strcpy(const char* source, char* destination, size_t dest_length, size_t copy_length)
{
    if ((NULL == source) || (NULL == destination) || (dest_length <= 0) || (copy_length <= 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (dest_length < copy_length)
    {
        copy_length = dest_length;
    }

    int err = 0;
    err |= memset_s(destination, dest_length, 0, dest_length);
    err |= memcpy_s(destination, dest_length,source, copy_length);
    if (err)
    {
        perror("Error when copying strings in s_strcpy");
        return false;
    }
    destination[dest_length-1] = '\0';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The better option is to use strcpy and leave error handling to the caller. Standardized, efficient, easy to read.

Comment: It makes no sense to write such a function. Why trust the callers dest_length argument if you don't trust the caller to give a buffer with correct size?

Comment: Maybe it is better for a program to crash than to truncate strings at arbitrary (*wrong*) sizes? #failfast

Comment: If [`[size_t] < 0`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) ever holds true, then you've got bigger concerns than making `strcpy` 'more secure'.

Comment: @4386427 I was hoping to see if there was a way to assert the dest_length to not be larger than the destination buffer size given. As far as I know there isn't a way. Then this function was the least trusting function I was able to write.

Comment: @Oka very true. Good catch. Should definitely be <=.

Comment: @ChrisMills-Bowling Nope.... In C there is no way to know how much allocated memory a pointer is pointing to. It's just impossible.

Comment: Show an example of how you would call this function. What's the `copy_length` parameter for? If  `copy_length` is smaller than `strlen(source)` your string will be truncated. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @Jabberwocky That would be the intent yes. Ideally it is a copy that makes it so the string you wanted from source of size copy_length from 0 is the only thing that shows up in the destination string followed by '\0' exclusively. If you wanted to copy a substring to the destination and keep the rest of destination it would probably be better to just use a memset_s for that region. Not really a good generic way to do that? But even then you could use this for substring prepending if you gave a destination size less than the destination buffer actual size.

Comment: @ChrisMills-Bowling there is no way to know the _destination buffer actual size_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky right, that decision to prepend would be on the caller. Since I have to trust the given destination length, it would be a hacky usage of this function, different from it's intended usage.